# Env variables show up undefined while using static site generation with NextJS 13's app router

Tags: next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing, static-site-generation

I am using NextJS 13's app router. I want to generate a bunch of pages during build time by fetching remote data. And the way I am trying to do this is by storing my api key in `.env.local` like so.

```
HEADLESS_API_KEY=topsecret
```

And then using this in my page `/app/articles/[slug]/page.tsx`, like so

```
export const dynamic = 'force-static';
export const dynamicParams = false;

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  console.log('top secret key', process.env.HEADLESS_API_KEY); // <-- shows undefined.
  const response = await fetchData(process.env.HEADLESS_API_KEY);
}

const Page = ({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) => {
  const { slug } = params
  return (
    <span>Page for {slug}</span>
  )
};

export default Page;
```

This code runs during build time and my understanding is that `generateStaticParams()` runs in the Node.js environment and should have access to `process.env.HEADLESS_API_KEY`. But it shows undefined when I try to log it to console.

Comment: Turns out my `env.local` was not placed at the root folder and was not picked up properly. Everything started working when I fixed it.